# String API Issue for non-hardcoded values

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to give an API call a string value to look up a list by. I have the following code:

```
$network_name = get_option('blogname');
$list_name = $network_name.' '.$cat_name;
echo "the list name is: ".$list_name;
$filters['list_name'] = $list_name;
$listid = $api->lists->getList( $filters );
```

When I echo the `$list_name` value it looks ok to me but doesn't return any results from the api call. However, if I make my code the following:

```
$list_name = 'School Soccer News & Notifications';
$filters['list_name'] = $list_name;
$listid = $api->lists->getList( $filters );
```

I get a result. The hardcoded value is the exact same as when I calculate the list name dynamically. Why would this be?

Update: Here is the output of the two:

```
The list name is: School Soccer News & Notifications
The list name is: School Soccer News & Notifications
```

They are identical.

EDIT: I did a string comparison and here is the code:

```
$cat = get_the_category( $post_ID );
$cat_name = $cat[0]->name;
$network_name = get_option('blogname');
$list_name = $network_name.' '.$cat_name;
$list_name_concate = $list_name;
$list_name = 'School Soccer News & Notifications';
$string_comaprison = strcmp( $list_name_concate, $list_name );
```

I got a result of 1 on the `$string_comaprison` so I guess they aren't the same.

I also did a var_dump and these are the results:

```
string(38) "School Soccer News & Notifications" 
string(34) "School Soccer News & Notifications"
```

The database is storing the `News & Notifications` as `News &amp; Notifications` and this is causing the issue.

Comment: Maybe there are leading (or trailling) spaces. Have you tried trimming $list_name ?

Comment: @litelite I tried and the same thing, no results returned.

Comment: what does the function get_option do?

Comment: @ThomasVdBerge It reads a value from the database. This is a wordpress function https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option

Comment: so $network_name.' '.$cat_name; is which url exactly? I do not see any api call, just a link that is being generated?

Comment: @ThomasVdBerge It isn't a URL, it's the name of the list I'm trying to retrieve from my API call. The api call is `$api->lists->getList`. I'm trying to pass this value to that API call

Comment: Ok got it. @litelite his suggestion was pretty solid then. Trim or case sensitive stuff? Can you maybe paste the output of both?

Comment: @ThomasVdBerge Done but they are the exact same.

Comment: @ThomasVdBerge I even tried to trim the individual strings but still, no results returned.

Comment: Is $network_name 'School Soccer' and $cat_name 'News & Notifications'?

Comment: I would try trimming $network_name and $cat_name individually before computing $list_name.

Comment: @GPicazo Yes and I tried that.

Comment: have you checked if they are identical by doing a `strcmp` . If that's non-zero it could give you a hint

Comment: Can you give us: `var_export($filters);` or `print_r($network_name.' '.$cat_name);`

Comment: @Twisty I did this and the one string is longer than the other for some reason. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert from the HTML format to the normal string format there is a function

```
$list_name=htmlspecialchars_decode($list_name)
```

Try that and it should work